# Filter particular row of Datatable for all column values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datatable in my application which has only one row which is as below.

```
pcode d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6

10001 0  1   1  0  1  1
```

Now i want to filter the datatable to get only the columns which has the value **1** except the pcode column(i.e i want only the columns d2,d3,d5,d6).The above datatable comes from database.Is there any way to filter the datatable or if i can do it with database table how can i do so?Any sugessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like:

```
List<string> result = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
            .Where(c => c.ColumnName != "pcode")
            .Where(c => dt.Rows[0][c].ToString() == "1")
            .Select(c => c.ColumnName)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: how can i convert this var to string?

Comment: if (dtble.Rows.Count > 0)


            {


                List<string> result = dtble.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
            .Where(c => dtble.Rows[0].Field<int>(c) == 1 && c.ColumnName != "ProductCode")
            .Select(c => c.ColumnName)
            .ToList();

                            }

        }

Comment: I am getting this error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'."